# How to hide proceed checkout button until cart price less then hundred and customer group is not retailer in magento?

Tags: magento

I want to hide proceed checkout button until cart  price is less then 100 and customer group is "retailer" and if price greater then 100 and customer group is "Retailer" then proceed checkout button show. How to achieve this functionality ? Help Me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your theme, edit the template file

> `checkout/onepage/link.phtml`

there is code

```
<?php if ($this->isPossibleOnepageCheckout()):?>
    <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Proceed to Checkout') ?>" class="button btn-proceed-checkout btn-checkout<?php if ($this->isDisabled()):?> no-checkout<?php endif; ?>"<?php if ($this->isDisabled()):?> disabled="disabled"<?php endif; ?> onclick="window.location='<?php echo $this->getCheckoutUrl() ?>';"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Proceed to Checkout') ?></span></span></button>
<?php endif?>
```

You will find this function `isPossibleOnepageCheckout()` in

```
Mage/Checkout/Block/Onepage/Link.php
```

You can extend this class and add your custom logic by which you can hide the checkout button.

Also in `/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php`

in `indexAction()`

write your condition so that user is redirected to cart page if condition is not fulfilled

Comment: it means my cart price rule condition and customer group condition code put in indexAction of OnepageController.php ?